# Gtk gtk_adjustment_animate_to_value

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtkmm

I recently stumbled upon a bug in my GTK+3 application with a very large tree view, which was that it didnt scroll properly anymore when calling `scroll_to_row()` (probably because it is too big).

So, I have overwritten the `scroll_to_row()` function, but my version does not feature the fancy animation that the original has. So I looked up in GTK+'s source code what `scroll_to_row()` actually does and found it uses a function that is not mentioned in the Gtk API - the function's name is `gtk_adjustment_animate_to_value`. Since this function has some complex internas, my questions are:

1. Can I use that function on my own or is that risky because it is not part of the official API?

or

2. Will I have to implement the animation myself? (Which will be complex, because of the needed thread dispatching)

I just hope that the bug is GTK+'s original function computing a wrong value for the adjustment, so I will still stay bug-free using the internal function.

Comment: What is `scroll_to_row()`? a [mcve] which reproduces the problem would be better than guess work.   a) Don't it is too risky. Since it is internal and undocumented it can be changed, or removed at any time.   b) You could write your own animation, but are you just working around your own bug? And why would you need threads?

Comment: Well, `scroll_to_row` refers to the following: [Link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1TreeView.html#ac7394be5aade86355daf4dd26fe1a28f)

Comment: and the bug is hard to reproduce but I  have tested it thouroughly and the function `scroll_to_row` works just fine with a `TreeView` of a few hundred rows, but with a few thousand rows it stops working (it scrolls, but pretty often not to the right row), so I guess this is not what they intended the function to do so I decided to make my own. (Btw, after using my own `scroll_to_row` function it works flawlessly :))

Comment: Also, I would need to use threads because I would have to time the animation etc and since GTK is not thread safe this involves using Dispatchers. And thanks thats what I pretty much wanted to know that it is not safe using the function :/ But maybe you know a way to make animation without threads? Thanks anyways :D

Comment: OK you are talking about c++ and gtkmm and not the c API for GTK+. `void Gtk::TreeView::scroll_to_row` is available in gtkmm only. To do the animations you really do not need to use threads.

Comment: If you are calling GTK+ functions from another thread, that is your problem. Use `gdk_threads_idle_add()` instead.